# Total size of database is bigger than sum of each table size in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Total DB size:

```
5620sam=# SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('5620sam'));
 pg_size_pretty
----------------
 72 GB
(1 row)
```

Files size on the disk:

```
# du --apparent-size -h /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/
<...>
74G     /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/
```

But if I sum the size of each of the tables (with index) separately, I get 3 times less ~ 20 Gb:

```
5620sam=# SELECT
    table_name,
    pg_size_pretty(table_size) AS table_size,
    pg_size_pretty(indexes_size) AS indexes_size,
    pg_size_pretty(total_size) AS total_size
FROM (
    SELECT
        table_name,
        pg_table_size(table_name) AS table_size,
        pg_indexes_size(table_name) AS indexes_size,
        pg_total_relation_size(table_name) AS total_size
    FROM (
        SELECT ('"' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '"') AS table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
    ) AS all_tables
    ORDER BY total_size DESC
) AS pretty_sizes;
```

[Output - get ~ 20 Gb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hZ9p.png)

What happened to another 50 gigabytes? Where can I find them? VACUUM FULL does not help, do it every night.

Comment: Could be stale files in the datadir. See if https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109092/how-to-reclaim-space-taken-by-an-index-that-partially-built is relevant?

Comment: It's possible. The question is how to delete old files without damaging the structure of the database.

Comment: Maybe you won't have to delete anything. The first step is to find where is the data that is not accounted for in your query. You may also pg_dump/drop/pg_restore the database if you're not confident in the manual deletion process.

Comment: pg_dump/drop/pg_restore the database - work fine, the database has become the normal size.

Comment: same thing is happening to me now... the DB size is growing 1 Gig every hour, but tables are not growing... I am over 10 times my expected size